# Inline radio with label up/down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the [inline radio in bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline) with the label up or down the radio.

If you take the official example, you have:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> 2
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> 3
  </label>
</div>
```

What can I do to align the label up or down?

[image: Label up]

Edit: [A failed attempt](http://plnkr.co/edit/hVVaF3a87VH0jNGrNqtd?p=preview) (not aligned and the checkbox doesn't display a clickable pointer)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "align the label up or down"

Comment: @sn3ll Sorry it wasn't clear... I've added a picture of label up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what importance or significance does the `form-check-input` hold in your page? Is there a script that uses this class to do some actions?

I noticed that "form-check-input" is having a negative margin of `-1.25rem` defined, if you remove the class or replace it with `form-check-label` it aligns just fine.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        1 <br /><input class="form-check-label" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        2 <br /><input class="form-check-label" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        3 <br /><input class="form-check-label" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">
    </label>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

DEMO : http://plnkr.co/edit/bs0PWCX1J3Z8XnpdpolN?p=preview

**EDIT:**

The above solution does not center things when the label text is longer, to make it work, we could use bootstrap predefined class `text-center` and wrap the entire label element in it like so:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        1 <br />
        <input class="" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
    </label>
    </div>
```

UPDATED DEMO : http://plnkr.co/edit/CQumOaFUOrm2SSLyc5Ru?p=preview

Comment: Almost there... When the label is longer, the checkbox is not aligned in the center: http://plnkr.co/edit/5mcopipYraqHJG5JDeCV?p=preview

Comment: wrap the entire label around <div> element would be the solution to make it work with label text of any length. I have updated my answer to reflect that.......

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you might want to try the following:

Bottom alignment:

```
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"><br /> 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"><br /> 2
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"><br /> 3
        </label>
    </div>
```

Top alignment:

```
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            1 <br /><input class="form-check-input" style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            2 <br /><input class="form-check-input" style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            3 <br /><input class="form-check-input" style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that they are not aligned and the checkbox doesn't display a clickable pointer: https://plnkr.co/edit/hVVaF3a87VH0jNGrNqtd?p=preview

Comment: Regarding pointer, you can use style="cursor: pointer;" in the input tag like so: <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1" style="cursor: pointer;">

Comment: For the alignment you have to adjust the padding/margins for the elements.  You have a lot of css going on in there.  To fix that specific issues use '.form-check-input { margin-left: 0px }`